# MX records of a domain - why are they editable from a hosting panel?

Tags: web-hosting, domains, dns

I have a domain, registered at company A. In the domain manager panel at this company I can edit DNS records of my domain, including MX records. That's understandable. I changed them.

But, the website which uses this domain is at company B. This comapany also has DNS records manager! It looks like it overwrites whatever I set at company A. How is that possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

toomanyairmiles is correct. once you delegate the name servers all of the dns config is going to go with it. if you're trying to lock down exactly whats happening when you do dns queries either get familiar with some command line tools or use some online dns tools such as the ones at unlocktheinbox.com. heres a link to the dns tools on their site: http://www.unlocktheinbox.com/dnslookup/mx/

Answer (score 2):

By adding the domain at Company B you gave them control of the DNS too.

Comment: Does setting the NS records at Company A to those of Company B mean "adding the domain at Company B"?

Comment: +1 This seems like a bit of bad UI at your registrar. I'm pretty sure most I've dealt with just hide their DNS options altogether once you transfer it to the host/elsewhere.

Comment: @user6456 yes basically delegating the name-servers delegates the DNS control.